# Django logging configuration working on local server but not on remote server

Tags: django, logging

I'm trying to configure django logging in the django settings file so that it logs django info and info for my application to a custom file for easy viewing. Here's my logging config:

```
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
        'file': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'file',
            'filename': 'logs/django_log.log',
            'backupCount': 10, # keep at most 10 log files
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5*1024*1024 bytes (5MB)
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'my_application': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            # required to avoid double logging with root logger
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

This works on my local manage.py test server, both with django events appearing and events that I log, initialized with `my_application` as the logger name. However, on my web server, the logging file is created and, oddly, only populated with occasional django `WARNING` messages. So, there is no permissions error or inability to access the log file. Since the same config works on my local, the config can't be the issue, and it clearly has only `INFO` level logs.

My server setup is taken from this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04 and uses Gunicorn with Nginx as a reverse proxy. Could the issue be with the configs for these? I'm stumped.

Additionally, where's a good best practice place to store this django log file?

Also, one related bonus question: What's a good best practice free/cheap service that can notify you if a specific error is logged? It seems like a good idea to set something like that up, but I don't think the django emailer is necessarily the most elegant or best.

Comment: Do you have multiple setting files?

Comment: what is the value of DEBUG setting ? while running on local server and gunicorn both?

Comment: @NageshDhope Yes, one for each of the 2 locations. But they both have that as their `LOGGING`. The DEBUG setting is True for the local, but False for the server.

Comment: can you try running gunicorn with --capture-output option?

Comment: @NageshDhope I can do that. It seems that that option ports std out/error to the errors file however, and I'm wary of changing gunicorn settings on my live server. I already have gunicorn std out and error ported to a file in my gunicorn settings. Do you think that option would fix the issue?